# Create WAL at interval, but only if data changed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, write-ahead-logging

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4 installation, and I have configured the `archive_timeout` setting to 5 minutes to improve the odds that I always have complete WAL file to apply in case of system failure.

However, this creates a LOT of big files, even if nothing has changed!  Is there a way to tell PostgreSQL to only create these WAL files at the timeout interval IF something has changed?

Comment: This has been addressed in up-to-date versions of Postgres (especially in Postgres 10)

Answer (score 0):

The `archive_timeout` and the `checkpoint_timeout` feed off each other in such a way that you will get a WAL switch once per whichever of those two settings is greater, even on a system that is otherwise idle.  So you can increase `checkpoint_timeout` to the maximum value (1 hour) to cut down on the idle log generation by a factor of 12.  The problem is that a checkpoint creates a record that needs to be archived, and the archival creates traffic that needs to be checkpointed (or at least, that PostgreSQL can't prove to itself doesn't need to be checkpointed)

There are a variety of ways around this, but most of them only work if you are running something less ancient than version 8.4.